# Linked list concepts

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Value of node in `*node=*(node->next)`, if node is the last element in linked list?

Value of node would be NULL or not?

> Given a singly linked list consisting of N nodes. The task is to remove duplicates (nodes with duplicate values) from the given list (if exists).
>   Note: Try not to use extra space. Expected time complexity is O(N). The nodes are arranged in a sorted way.

This solution didn't work for test case `2 2 2 2 2` (five nodes with equal values).

```cpp
Node *removeDuplicates(Node *root)
{
    if(root->next==NULL)
        return root;

    Node * t1=root;
    Node* t2=root->next;
    while(t2!=NULL)
    {
        if(t1->data==t2->data)
        {
            *t2=*(t2->next);
        }
        else
        {
            t1=t1->next;
            t2=t2->next;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

This worked:

```cpp
Node *removeDuplicates(Node *root)
{
    if(root->next==NULL)
        return root;

    Node * t1=root;
    Node* t2=root->next;
    while(t2!=NULL)
    {
        if(t1->data==t2->data)
        {
            if(t2->next==NULL)
            {
                t1->next=NULL;
                t2=NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                *t2=*(t2->next);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            t1=t1->next;
            t2=t2->next;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: if `node->next == nullptr`, then dereferencing (like in `*node=*(node->next)`) it is an error.

Comment: Likewise, if the list is empty then `root` itself is also null. `if(root->next==NULL)` should be `if(root==NULL)`. `while(t2!=NULL)` handles the case where `root->next` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't post the full code for something that is clearly homework but I wasn't sure how to properly articulate all of the points. I also haven't compiled and ran this because I didn't want to create my own Node class.

First we can talk about the algorithm. If your singly linked list is already sorted and NULL terminated then essentially we have a current node pointing to a node in the list and a travel node (nextNode) that walks down the list. The main thing we need to make sure we do is update the pointers to point to the next node once we've found a non-duplicate.

In the code below I've also added NULL checks which is incredibly important. Get in the habit of knowing exactly which state your variables could be in as it is easy to accidentally call a method on a null pointer which would cause the program to crash.

```
Node* removeDuplicates(Node* root)
{
  // Check that root isn't null before checking that its next pointer is also not NULL
  if (root == NULL || root->next == NULL)
    return root;

  // Set up our current node and the travel node
  Node* currentNode = root;
  Node* nextNode = root->next;

  // Until we've reached the end of the singly linked list
  while (nextNode != NULL)
  {
    // Find the next node that isn't a duplicate
    // Also check that we don't reach the end of the list
    while (nextNode->data == currentNode->data && nextNode != NULL)
      nextNode = nextNode.next;

    // Update the current node's next pointer to point to the travel node
    currentNode->next = nextNode;

    // Update the current node to its next for the next iteration
    currentNode = nextNode;

    // Update the next node being careful to check for NULL
    nextNode = nextNode == NULL ? NULL : nextNode->next;
  }

  return root;
}
```

This is not the only way to handle this problem. By reorganizing when you do certain checks and associations you can eliminate some of the NULL checks or make the program more clear. This is just one possible solution.